# Model binding to list in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am not able to retrieve a simple list on server side. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

```
public class TestList
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
}
```

Form:

```
@model List<SampleMVC4App.Controllers.TestList>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{           
    <input name="cust" value="1" type="hidden" />
    <input name="[1].id" value="de107502-284d-459b-80a1-762ce0860cd8" type="hidden" />    
    <input name="[1].name" value="test1" type="hidden" />    
    <input name="[1].location" value="location1" type="hidden" />    
    <a id="AddAnother" href="#">Add</a>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ICollection<TestList> cust) **<---Null**
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Your input fields' names look very strange. I am afraid they are incorrect.

Comment: Can we see how you are generating the form? Including the action that renders the view and the view itself?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have posted form markup. I am testing the functionality, so just rendered the View(). I am trying with static markup since I wasn't successful binding to objects. Similar to what Phil Haack has done in his example.

Comment: I suggest changing your form to use (the Razor equivalent of) `<%= Html.TextBoxFor( m => m[1].Name ) %>` and then testing that.

Comment: Dai, I am trying with hidden variables with unique id. By using index, i was able to retrieve it.

Comment: Sundeep, are you aware that RAZOR has a @html.hiddenfor()?

Comment: So when exactly are you creating a list?  It really looks like you're just posting a single item, while your controller is actually looking for a list.

Comment: Yes. I was trying with just static values to know how it works. Though I've single item in the page, it is available as cust[0] in the httppost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working for hours, I managed to work it out by changing below

```
<input name="cust" value="1" type="hidden" />
```

to

```
<input name="Index" value="1" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: Here is more information from Hanselman on model binding to a list: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
your model is right .
in the cshtml page try this

```
 @model List<SampleMVC4App.Controllers.TestList>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
    <h2>
        Index</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {           
        foreach(SampleMVC4App.Controllers.TestList tl in Model)
{
     @model.hiddenfieldfor () // Like this your list will be rendered.
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Edit(FormCollection fm) to get all the form elements from the view. Then handle the returned variables in your httpPost action. That would make it easier to debug when seeing what elements are returned.

I found this post by Scott Allen to be helpful when I was working with HttpPOST
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx